# Tooltips in fullcalendar won't show in combination with bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, tooltip

I am working on a private Codeigniter project and want to display some events in my view with the help of fullcalendar.

So far - so good. But i want to display more information than the events name and time, i want to display aditional information like room und lecturer. The fullcanender docs reccomend this solution: [event-tooltip-demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-tooltip-demo) .
But that only works as long as i am not using bootstrap. As soon as i am integrating bootstrap.css, the tooltips won't show.
Even the official example on codepen behaves the same, when you add Bootstrap. Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

Edit:
By the way, here are some additional information, that might help. When i am hovering the event while bootstrap.css in included, the following element shows up in the Inspector:

```
<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip" id="tooltip_zvh8nhyqlo" aria-hidden="false" x-placement="top" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(488px, 179px, 0px);"><div class="tooltip-arrow" style="left: 65px;"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">Lecture</div></div>
```

So that seems to be like indended.

And here is teh order of my "imports":

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.0/main.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.0/locales-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js"></script>
```

As soon as i uncomment the first line (bootstrap.css) the tooltips are shown. Same behaviour in the official codepen example. Not matter if i use Bootstrap 4 or 3

Comment: as far as i know, i used bootstrap tooltip and bootstrap modal dialog in one of my Project, but they cannot work together, they were showing simultaneously..
but ur case is different, u r saying tooltip won't show by including bootstrap.css, in that case i would say there must be code issues.

U need to put some of ur code so that we can see the actual problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: "Any ideas?"...yes, use bootstrap's built-in tooltips instead - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/ . (The reason for your problem is that tooltip.js's markup/CSS conflicts with stuff in the bootstrap CSS. But if you're already using bootstrap which provides tooltips then it doesn't really make much sense to add another library as well).

Comment: After looking at some other values in the inspector i found out, that with the included bootstrap.css the opacity value was set to 0. I worked aound that by manually setting .tooltips opacity to 1. But that is just some workaround

Comment: Yes. Just use bootstrap's tooltips instead

Answer (score 2):

The reason of your problem is the Tooltip conflicts with bootstrap CSS. You can easily solve the conflict by just adding 2 simple CSS.

You need to add `opacity: 1;` on `tooltip` class and `background-color: transparent;` on `tooltip-inner` class to get the same result as before adding the bootstrap.

Here is codepen with those updates:
https://codepen.io/sasiddiqui/pen/oNxzBMe

Comment: Thank you very much Sami Ahmed Siddiqui. Thats exactly the solution I was looking for.